# How can I configure git to reject large files?

Tags: git, quota, gitolite, hook

For the 3rd time a developer committed a large file in our git repository (over 100MB).  It's really a pain to cleanup.  How can I configure git and/or gitolite to prevent large files from ever being committed into the repo?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hooks to accomplish this.
It has been discussed on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147699/limiting-file-size-in-git-repository

Comment: Although when it's one given developer who's the problem, I'd be inclined to revoke push privileges from that one...